# Do solutions of $\dot{x} = \frac{x}{t^2} + t$ exist satisfying $x(0) =0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Suppose we have the 1-dimensional ODE 
\begin{equation}
\dot{x} = \frac{x}{t^2} + t
\end{equation}
Do there exist solution curves with initial condition $x(0)=0$?  If you proceed in a standard way then you would get as solution formula
\begin{equation}
x= C {\rm e}^{-1/t} + {\rm e}^{-1/t}  \int^{t}_0  \tau {\rm e}^{1/\tau}  d \tau
\end{equation} 
but then the expression in the integral explodes! This does not imply that solution curves with $x(0)=0$ do not exist. How to proceed with such existence results?

Comment: If such $x$ existed you'd get $x'(0)=\dfrac{x(0)}0+0$.

Comment: @Git Gud  Not sure what you are trying to say. But the limiting behaviour for $x/t^2$ is unclear. For example, if $x$ would go faster than something of $O(t^2)$ we would be ok but if this is the case is unclear.

Comment: What I'm drying to say is that such a solution can't possibly have $0$ in its domain.

Comment: Well try solving for example $dx/dt = -x/t +t $ (which can be  solved in the standard way) and you will see that this is not the issue.

Comment: It is true. Whatever you may get from that is the solution satisfies the differential equation when $t\neq 0$, but for $t=0$ it can't work. That a solution can be extended to $0$ doesn't change the fact that any solution to the differential equation you propose isn't defined on $0$.

Comment: Looking at $$\begin{equation}
\dot{x} = \frac{x}{t^k} + t
\end{equation}$$ it seems that the condition makes a serious problem as soon as $k>1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your original problem is not a [Cauchy problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_problem)

The usual setup for solving differential equations is that you are given a function $f: [a,b] \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and a point $(x_0, y_0)$ and you want to find a function $y:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ which satisfies two conditions:

- $f(x,y(x)) = y'(x)$ for all values $x\in[a,b]$
- $y(x_0)=y_0$

In your case, you only defined the function $f$ on $(a,b]\times\mathbb R$, since $f(t, x)=\frac{x}{t^2}+t$ in your case. Your equation has many solutions. For example, taking $x(t)=0$ creates a function that satisfies $f(t, x(t))=\dot x(t)$ for every $t\in (0,1]$.

Comment: Yes, I know it can have many solutions. But I am really looking for the existence of a family of solutions satisfying $x(0)=0$.

Comment: @Novo I suggest you look at the family of functions satisfying the equation and has a value of $c$ at $t=1$. Then look at which of those satisfy $x(0)=0$, if there even are any (besides $0$).

Comment: Aaaah work backwards I see Thankies

Answer (score 1):

Set $x(t)=t^2 y(t)$, then the original equation becomes:

$$t^2 \dot y(t)+2t y(t)=y(t)+t\tag{1}$$

The $y(0)=0$ solution is:

$$y(t)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2t}-\frac{e^{-1/t}}{2t^2}Ei(1/t)\tag{2}$$

When $t\to 0$, we have

$$y(t)\approx -t - 3 t^2 - 12 t^3 - 60 t^4...\tag{3}$$